# efficient algorithm for 1d to 3d index correspondence in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to set up a correspondence between a regular grid of 3d cells and 1d indexes of those cells. So I want a way to map back and forth between triplets of integers (*i, j, k*) and integers *cellnum*. Speed in this mapping is critical.

**PROBLEM ILLUSTRATION:**

Suppose that each dimension of a 3d box is divided into *num_divs* cells. Then the mapping from (*i, j, k*) to a unique, dictionary-order index of the cell is made lightning fast via the following numpy indexing trick:

```
indexing_array = np.arange(num_divs**3).reshape((num_divs, num_divs, num_divs))
```

As an example, suppose we have the following arrays storing the x, y, and z cell indices of *Npts* points:

```
Npts = 1e6
xidx = np.random.random_integers(0, num_divs-1, Npts)
yidx = np.random.random_integers(0, num_divs-1, Npts)
zidx = np.random.random_integers(0, num_divs-1, Npts)
```

The array storing the *cellnum* of each triplet can be computed extremely efficiently via:

```
output_cellnum_array = indexing_array[xidx, yidx, zidx]
```

The *output_cellnum_array* is a one-dimensional array of *Npts* points. Each value is an integer storing the dictionary-order of each (*i, j, k*) triplet. The above line takes just 40ms on my laptop, my target benchmark for the following question:

**QUESTION:**

How can I achieve the same level of speed to go in the reverse direction? Given a one-dimensional array of integers, *input_cellnum_array*, how can I compute arrays *xidx, yidx, zidx* with comparable speed?

**UNWORKABLY SLOW SOLUTION:**

Running a for loop with the following function returns the correct result, but is orders of magnitude too slow for my application:

```
def reverse_indexer(single_cellnum, num_divs):
    i = single_cellnum/(num_divs*num_divs)
    remainder = single_cellnum - (num_divs*num_divs*i)
    j = remainder/num_divs
    remainder -= j*num_divs
    k = remainder % num_divs
    return i, j, k
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [numpy.unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) and [numpy.ravel_multi_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html). While `numpy.unravel_index` maps the 1d index to the multi-dimensional index, `numpy.ravel_multi_index` transforms the mutli-dimensioal index into a 1d index:

```
id_1d = np.arange(9)

# getting the indices of the multi-dimensional array
idx,idy,idz = np.unravel_index(id_1d,(3,3,3))

(idx,idy,idz)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))

# getting the 1d indecis
np.ravel_multi_index((idx,idy,idz),(3,3,3))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Brilliant! You're right, @plonser - this is **exactly** what I was looking for! God, numpy is just so great. Thanks a million.